# Update a circular array in MongoDB with Java

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, atomic, circular-buffer

I've created [this](http://pastebin.com/eXdN6pAN) class to create a circular buffer of Integers,
i need to write it to work for mongodb, i've done the add with an increment and set but i don't know how to create the remove method without downloading and reuploading all array, isn't there a more efficient method to do it keeping atomicity?

Comment: With Javascript you can access specific array indexes like this: `{ 'arrayfield.5': value }`. But I am not sure how to do this best with the Java driver.

Answer (score 0):

For the "add" action, you can use the $push operator with $slice modifier when you do the update in MongoDB, see [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/#examples).

For the "remove" action you can use the $pull operator, see [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#examples).

Comment: read the full question and the code, is not a normal array, it's a circular buffer array optimized for writing, i don't need only to push and pull the elements.

Comment: Ok. You mean you're concerned that $push + $slice are not fast enough?

Comment: If you're concerned about the performance of the remove operation, maybe you should consider to replace an item by an invalid value instead of removing the item from the list

Comment: if i replace it with an invalid value how can i replace it after that?

Comment: You just ignore the invalid value whenever you read it. I mean, suppose your circular array has [a,b,c,d] and last=3. Now you remove b, so you have [a,nil,c,d] and last=3. Now you add e, so you get [e,nil,c,d] and last=0. Then you add f so you get[e,f,c,d] and last=1. Is this an acceptable behavior?

Comment: i want that the space is avaible right after the remotion

Comment: Engineering is all about tradeoffs. You'll probably need to give up something :-)

Comment: i ended up storing all in local ram. i'll access it from requests